# Android Text To Speech -- Check if any app is using TTS service

Tags: android, text-to-speech

Is there a way to determine whether "any" app is currently using the Android Text-To-Speech engine?  Meaning, they've created an instance of Text-To-Speech (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/speech/tts/TextToSpeech.html) and is ready to use it?

I am trying to work around a bug in several apps that assume when "any" accessibility manager service is enabled, that it is actually the "talkback" service.  As a result of this bug, when I enable "my" accessibility service, the buggy apps startup TTS and start talking.

As a fix, when my accessibility service is enabled, I will check to see if anyone has enabled TTS, and if so, disable my service as to not annoy the user.  I will then inform the user that my service is disabled because they are running on a buggy platform.

Thanks,
J

Comment: You just want to detect whether talkback option is turned On or Off in your app???

Comment: Sorry for the confusion.  I want to determine whether other apps have turned on the Text-To-Speech engine.

Here is a link to provide more context: http://developer.samsung.com/forum/thread/samsung-devices-and-accessibility-services/77/204387

The issue is that some apps assume that "talkback" is the ONLY accessibility service on the device, so when users enable MY accessibility service, the faulty apps start TTS and start talking.  I'd like to detect this behavior so I can notify the user.

Comment: Then this is the fault of those Buggy apps, What you can do about it?

Comment: Unfortunately, there is not much :( Samsung won't fix their faulty devices.  If I can determine whether a buggy app is installed, then I can just disable my app and notify the user.  The problem is that I do not know how to detect the fault app.  If within my accessibility service, I can determine if an app has enabled TTS, then I can assume that they are *buggy* and turn myself off.

Comment: Unfortunately, I haven't seen anything like this...

Comment: Apps (probably using WebView?) should only be speaking if the system reports that a speaking-type accessibility service is installed. How does you service report its feedback type, either via AccessibilityServiceInfo or XML metadata?

Comment: Also, there are no APIs that will allow an app to determine whether another app has a connection to TTS, nor would something like this be reliable in your situation. Google Now, for one, maintains a TTS connection.

Comment: Thanks Alan for the comments. I agree that apps "should" be speaking only when the speaking-type accessibility service is installed, but that doesn't seem to be the case on some Samsung devices :( Therefore, I need a work around for those faulty samsung apps that talk without checking if the correct accessibility service is enabled.  Unfortunately, disabling my app on all samsung devices will not work.

Comment: Hi Jon did you get any solution for your question